# Why can I not use multiple statements in for loop in the following way?

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax-error, indentation

```
for x in chats:
        a.append(x[0])
        b.append(x[1])
        dialogues.append(x[2])
```

It throws the error : inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: You appear to be inconsistently using tabs and spaces

Comment: I am just using one tab which is required

Comment: Delete all your tabs. Then retype them. If that doesn't help, try a different editor, it may convert some tabs into spaces.

Comment: ok i got it. Tab does not work. Spaces do, in my editor. Thanks a lot

Comment: Since spaces are the preferred way to indent the lines (see [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)) switching from tabs to spaces is a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 4):

For indentation, you must use either only tabs of only spaces, but not both intermixed.

Most of the Python community uses multiples of 4 spaces. Some editors mix up things.

Comment: Fun fact, what is important is to match an indent level when un-indenting. Which allows stuff like `if X: (7 spaces) if Y: (13 spaces): print("hello") (-20 spaces) if Z: (1 space) print("world")`. To avoid, of course.